# Get HTML string from byte[] when using doDynamicCompression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a response filter where I use the following code to get the HTML string from the byte array.

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
    var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    // do stuff
}
```

if I set doDynamicCompression to true in web.config like the code below, the string looks like [this](http://cl.ly/IoZn)

```
  <system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Is there a secure way of getting the HTML string that works with compression and without?

Comment: may be you should wach at System.IO.Compression.GzipStream

Answer (score 1):

You could use `GZipStream` to decompress the content, but since you're then working the results in your response filter you no longer have the compression (but you have the header saying you do), so you'll have to do the work of compressing it again.

This means that you lose all the advantage of having it done for you automatically.

For that reason, I'd suggest you write your own filter to handle the compression yourself (the one gotcha I found with this is that you don't want to flush the gzipstream you use when your filter is flushed, though you should still flush the output stream).

(How does your code given handle it if a large piece of text was sent in chunks and a chunk ends part-way though a character?)

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe a response filter is the wrong approach for me, I'm trying to add a piece of HTML before the end body tag. Do you know if there is a way to access the HTML before it's compressed?

Comment: How about using master pages so they all have the same frame the the HTML? Should be a lot simpler if applicable.